# shouldInterceptRequest equivalent for Android Froyo (2.2)

Tags: android, flash, webview

I have a Flash file played in an Android application and interacting with it.
The Android version of this application is 2.3 .
The Flash file is embedded in an Android's WebView and interacting with the application through the: `shouldInterceptRequest` method of the: `WebViewClient`:

```
WebView web_Player;
web_Player.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {         
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    //CODE CODE CODE
    }
}
```

**The problem**:
I need this code to support Android 2.2, which doesn't know the `shouldInterceptRequest` method.
How can I overcome this issue? In what other way can the Flash file communicate with the application in Android 2.2?

Comment: Anyone? Common, I'm a bit stuck here...

Comment: Note: even 2.3 doesn't know shouldInterceptRequest method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using:

```
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url){}
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: Not if you also would modify resources (CSS, JS, etc) for the page.